# Did similar-sounding words like wet/weight/wait come to existence before the invention of writing?

Tags: etymology, homophones

I am not an expert in languages and this is my first question here...

To my understanding, most of the languages were spoken before writing was discovered/evolved. What would cause a language to have same/similar sounding words with different meanings when the language was spoken? Wouldn't it cause more confusion when spelling could not distinguish the different words as there was no writing?

I can think of some other examples such prey/pray or ate/eight which sound similar but their meanings aren't related.

Did these words evolve/change in pronunciation over time, or were they used with similar meanings even a long time back, since before writing was a thing?

Comment: This may be better on Linguistics.SE.

Comment: One thing an answer could touch on is that we distinguish homophones through more than spelling. Context, syntax, and other elements can all be cues for how we hear *weight*/*wait*. "Before writing" may be too long ago to answer in English, since our earliest notions of the language *come from writing*. But if you adjust the question, we could speak to the potential for non-literate folk to parse homophones just fine.

Comment: I think you meant just weight/wait, since "wet" isn't a homophone of either of those.

Comment: Weight & wait aren't homophones in modern Northern BrE. They're rhymes to eight & late.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Even to me in the English Midlands, _eight_ and _late_ have the same vowel. Can you clarify the distinction you mean?

Comment: @KateBunting - I don't know phonetics, & the 'auto' translators give the same for both, so best I can do is ayit vs laate. There's no uptilt in late, the 'a' is flat. 'Eight' might be considered to have a dipthong ay - eet. Yorkshire long 'a's have very little inflection, they are very flat.

Comment: I'd guess a monophthong *late* might be /lɛ:t/ but **either** this is actually outside the scope of the question **or** it demonstrates that the question has fallen into a fallacy. Which it is should be the basis of an answer, not further comment, please.

Comment: Do you mean before the invention of printing?